# How to add class to the error messages in Laravel automaticallly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

**In the Blade i use**

```
{{ $errors->first('VehicleNumber') }} to throw the errors.
```

**But How can i add the div class to it.**

I tried

```
{{ $errors->first('VehicleNumber', array('class' => 'error')) }}
```

But It throws Array to String Conversion Error.

I don't need

```
<div class="error">
{{ $errors->first('VehicleNumber') }}
</div>
```

If i do so the class error will always appear.

But I want to appear the class only if the error exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the 2nd function parameter to format the message:

```
{{ $errors->first('VehicleNumber', '<div class="error">:message</div>') }}
```

Answer (score 0):

as this post seems a bit outdated but is still quite high ranked in Google here is what worked for me as the solution provided by The Shift Exchange isn't quite right.

In order to interpret the html in your blades, you'll need to use the following syntax:

```
{!! $errors->first('VehicleNumber', '<div class="error">:message</div>') !!}
```

Note the difference between {{ }} and {!! !!}. The second syntax interprets HTML, the first doesn't.

Hope that helps someone.